# Cordova AppRate plugin tries to vote for himself

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I installed plugin [`cordova.apprate`](https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate) into the game written on HTML5 for iOS. Plugin allows you to vote for the application.

In folder `my_project/plugins/org.pushandplay.cordova.apprate/www`, I found the file `preferences.js` and changed the example `appStoreID` to my app id:

```
AppRatePreferences = {
  useLanguage: "en",
  displayAppName: "AppRate plugin",
  promptAtLaunch: true,
  promptAgainForEachNewVersion: true,
  daysUntilPrompt: 1,
  usesUntilPrompt: 3,
  appStoreID: {
    ios: "913573164"
  }
};
```

The game is approved and is already sold. But the plugin doesn't work as it should - instead of offering to vote for the game, he offers to vote for yourself:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the `displayAppName` parameter?

That should be the name of your app.

```
displayAppName: "Name of your app here",
```

Quickly change it and release a new version on iTunes, that should solve the problem

Comment: @benka Does this plugin knows the user has already rated the app and would disable the popup in the future ? Or does it repeatedly bring up the popup even after the user rated the app ?

Comment: i believe it does and won't bring up the rating notification once the user rated it. It was a long time though since I last worked with this plugin but looking at it's github page, it looks like you can set it up different ways. For example you can ask for rating every time you push out a new version.
For available settings check out it's page: https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate